# Serving dockerized microservices over HTTPS

Tags: docker, ssl, networking, https, gunicorn

I'm currently struggling with docker and SSL. Let me give you an overview on what I'm trying to do.

I built a microservice-based architecture which is composed by a react web application and some "backend" services written in python and exposed with gunicorn on docker containers. I need to serve it over SSL because of Auth0 which needs the https communication. So, I built the server, bought a domain and got the SSL certificate for the domain with let's encrypt.

Now, here are the troubles, since mi services communicates to each other with a docker network, say `services-network`. For this reason they refer each other with the url `service:port/example.

At the moment I'm able to successfully connect to my web app with https but whenever this tries to contact the "backend" services the connection is refused because of it came from a non-secure resource (I used `http://service:port/endpoint`).

I tried to use the let's encrypt certificate generated for the webapp but the communication is blocked with message `requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='service', port=8081): Max retries exceeded with url: /endpoint (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'service' doesn't match 'domain.com'",),))`

I understand that a possible workaround for this error is to make the services communicate each other without using the docker network but the external one. Anyway I think that is not a good practice and that the communication among containers needs to be done through the docker network.

Finally, my question is: which is the best way to make the containers communicate through https over the docker network?

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to use nginx as a reverse proxy. You would configure it normally and set it to `proxy_pass <dockerIp:port>`.

Many people like to use [`traefik.io`](https://github.com/traefik/traefik) which has many features including [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) integration.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the reply! I can't understand whether you are suggesting to do "external requests" or not. Can you tell me what "proxy_pass dockerIp:port" is expected to do?

Comment: Is traefik an alternative to the nginx reverse proxy?